# Is it possible to do Reduce-Side Join in Mongodb MapReduce

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I read that the Joins like Reduce-Side, Replicated and Composite joins are supported in Hadoop framework. Is there any kind of support for these joins in Mongodb?

Use-case for me is there is a collection of events and its occurrences for each user logged. Sample of that is

```
{_id: uniqueEventId, event: login, userId: abc}
```

There is another collection with details about the user and the attributes for the user is not fixed. Sample doc of that is

```
{_id: abc, city: "SF", state: CA, customfield1: value1...}
```

The result that I need is the aggregation on the events, userId and also need the user details populated. Sample,

```
{userId: abc, event: login, count:23, city: SF, state: CA}
```

so that I can query based on state or city which has max login events and similar kind of queries.

I considered embedding user doc as a part of events doc, but if there is a change in user attributes, I need to update literally all of the events collection which will be huge.

I took a look at the ways to merge two collection from this [link](http://tebros.com/2011/07/using-mongodb-mapreduce-to-join-2-collections/) but this is not exactly useful, since the key on which I need to run the reduce function is a compound key(userId + event).

Answer (score 1):

I would like to note this JOIN cannot be used in realtime to your app and by doing it you are breaking MongoDB, however, yes; there is a way to map-reduce a JOIN.

In your first MR that gets the:

```
{_id: abc, city: "SF", state: CA, customfield1: value1...}
```

You just emit this row and write it to a new collection. Then in your second MR where you get:

```
{userId: abc, event: login, count:23, city: SF, state: CA}
```

You make `userId` actually `_id`:

```
var map = function(){
    emit(this.userId, {this.event, //etc});
}
```

Or a compound key:

```
var map = function(){
    emit({o: this.userId, e: this.event}, {this.event, //etc});
}
```

Then you reduce as normal but change the command, or rather call, to the server so that the `out` option within the MR actually points to the result of your first MR adding a `reduce` or `merge` command on the `out` option to make the two collections join on duplicate `_id`s:

```
db.col.mapreduce( map, reduce, { out: {merge:collection_from_first_mr} })
```

That is basically how it works.

Going back to my first notice at the start of this answer. This is not SQL JOINs and they should not be treated as such. The JS engine is:

- Slow
- Single threaded
- Not actually MongoDB or Server-side, it is actually a built in JS engine to MongoDB

If the collection gets out of control or this command is run in realtime to your app you could easily see performance problems of other JavaScript (remember it is single threaded) that needs to run on your server does productive stuff.

#### Edit

> so that I can query based on state or city which has max login events and similar kind of queries.

Wouldn't the login occur in that city though? So maybe the login row should contain a city and state field. This won't need updating and sound kind of odd that it would since that login would happen there, not anywhere else so:

> I need to update literally all of the events collection which will be huge.

Becomes obsolete since the login event will not need updating because it happened in the state/city it was recorded in which is correct.

So I would actually go for a schema of:

```
{_id: uniqueEventId, event: login, userId: abc, state: '', city: ''}
```

And aggregate on that.

Comment: I am aware of the performance impact of this kind of join so these are to be run as background jobs. What I am not able to do here, if there is compound key that I emit from one collection and the other collection does not have the one of the field in the compound key. Ex: `{userId: abc, event: login}` is the compound key from collection1 and `{userId: abc, event: null}` for collection2. In this scenario it looks like its not possible to join at all. Is that right?

Comment: @Sundar Yea I didn't think of that since I wrote that answer very quickly one time. Mind you I don't think you are joining on a compound key here since you want all login events and their user detail right? Or just all events and their user detail? Either way it sounds like the event is unique to the event collection and wouldn't be good to join on in an SQL tech either.

Comment: @Sundar You would do this join normally on just user _id and then post aggregate after doing this join the data you want it, this is the big flaw with this idea is that you must aggregate effectively twice (just like a real JOIN).